# incluir casas decimais Valor 1500 e deixá-lo como 1500.00 sem virgula!

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu tenho um valor inteiro de 1500 na variável valormonetario e quero enviar para outra variável valorrecebe como 1500.00 . Como fazer em c#.
Já tentei conversões e nada acontece...No final,  a variável Valordecimal deve ser preenchida como 1500.00. Fiz várias formas e nada acontece. Não sei o que fazer.
Parte da rotina é essa;

```
                string valorreceb = ((registro.Cells["Valor"].Value.ToString()));
                valorreceb = valorreceb.ToString().Replace(".", ",");
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(registro.Cells["Valor"].Value.ToString()) || valorreceb == "0")
                {

                    String valor2 = "0.00";
                    cepXml.AppendFormat("\t\t<Valor>{0}</Valor>\r\n", valor2);
                }
                else
                {
                    decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(valorreceb);
                    string Valordecimal = Convert.ToString(d);
                    string sVariavelNova = Valordecimal.Replace(",", ".");

                    cepXml.AppendFormat("\t\t<Valor>{0}</Valor>\r\n", Valordecimal);
                }
```

Comment: Não sei bem como fazer na tecnologia que está usando, que nem sei qual é exatamente. Mas posso quase te garantir que ficar fazendo conversão, `Replace()` e coisas do tipo é o jeito errado. Você provavelmente tem que usar [`Culture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: por incrível que pareca! Consegui. a rotina abaixo:                        CultureInfo _ptBR = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR");
                        d.ToString("00.00", _ptBR);
                      string teste=  string.Format(_ptBR, "{0:00,00}", d);

Comment: Achei que iria conseguir, eu não respondi porque a pergunta não deixava tão claro o contexto do que está fazendo. Eu poderia errar. Pode postar como resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Você não precisa de nada especial, o valor estando em `decimal` o método `ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)` já faz isso, você só precisa passar um `CultureInfo` que use ponto como separador decimal, que pode ser por exemplo o `InvariantCulture`

```
decimal valor = 1500;
string formatado = valor.ToString("f2", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

No caso o `"f2"` indica ao método `ToString` que queremos formatar o valor usando um ponto fixo com duas casas decimais, você pode ver mais sobre a formatação padrão de números na [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)